# Subquery to find the 3rd highest cost of the products sold

Tags: mysql

i have been trying to find the 3rd highest cost of the product sold.
from table tblproducts.i am using mysql server 5.6.

i used the below query:

```
select name
from tblproducts
where cost IN
(select distinct top 3 cost
from tblproducts
order by cost desc);
```

but when i run the query it shows the below error:

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3 cos
t
from tbbproducts
order by cost dec)' at line 4**

.....................
someone kindly help me with the syntax to correct this error.

thankyou.

Comment: select name from tblproducts where cost IN (select distinct top 3 cost from tblproducts order by cost desc); (correction:i have used IN.. kindly help me with the top 3 syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM tblproducts t1
WHERE (3) = ( SELECT COUNT(t2.cost)
              FROM tblproducts t2
              WHERE t2.cost >= t1.cost
            )
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

**Update:**

The above query works fine so long as there is no possibility for products with duplicate costs in `tblproducts`.  If there be the chance for cost duplicates, then we can modify the query as follows:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM tblproducts t1
WHERE (3) = ( SELECT COUNT(t2.cost)
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cost FROM tblproducts) t2
              WHERE t2.cost >= t1.cost
            )
```

Comment: ya dat worked..but can you help me with the top(3) syntax if possible?

Comment: `TOP(3)`is not valid MySQL syntax, it is only used in SQL Server and Access.  The analogy of `TOP` in MySQL is `LIMIT`, but this might not help you with the query you are trying to do.

Comment: i wanted explaination of the query which you have wriitten

Comment: For each record in your table, it counts how many other records have a cost which is higher.  When it finds a record where that number is 3, then it has its answer.